Ensuring totals are excluded when downloading a matrix in Power BI Service
In Power BI service, I want to download a matrix (which is based on a field parameter). When I download it, the file includes totals that are not shown in the matrix in Power BI.
In the matrix, both 'Column subtotals' and 'Row subtotals' are turned off and all the things in 'Specific column'are truned off. (The measure in the matrix is counts.) I also read online that the issue might be resolved by fully expanding the matrix, but unfortunately, this does not work either.
How can I ensure that the totals do not appear in the download?

Use a table visual or a paginated report. Matrix will always contain the subtotals in extractions.
